# Implement the take function with list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, take

How would you implement `take` with a list comprehension?

My approach so far:

```
take2 :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take2 n xs = [x | x <- xs, [x..n]]
```

Comment: Why would you use list comprehension for this? Yes it is strictly speaking possible, but it is rather inelegant to do so here.

Comment: for practice and curiosity :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental reason why list comprehensions are not a good fit for the `take` function is this:

The `take` function **stops the evaluation** of the argument list after `n` elements.

But lists comprehensions **always evaluate all elements** of the list in the generator. There is no break-statement in Haskell.

---

You can use some trick to truncate the list before or after using it in the list comprehension, but there is no real point of doing so. That would be similar to first using normal `take` to truncate the list, then using a list comprehension just to return the result.

Answer (score 7):

We can use a `zip` approach here, and enumerate over both the elements, and indices, like:

```
take2 :: (Num i, Enum i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take2 n xs = [x | (x, _) <- zip xs [1..n]]
```

Or with the `ParallelListComp` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

take2 :: (Num i, Enum i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
take2 n xs = [x | x <- xs | _ <- [1..n]]
```

But actually `take` is probably not a function that is a good fit for list comprehension in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Without List Comprehension

```
take' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
take' _ [] = []
take' _ [x] = [x]
take' n all@(x : xs)
        | (n > length all) = error "Index too large"
        | (n == length all) = all
        | (n == 0) = []
        | (n < length all) =  x : [] ++ (take' (n-1) xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
take' :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take' n xs = [xs !! i | i <- [0..n-1]]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers